# How to remove Post Excerpts Button?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove "Full Article" button from post excerpts ( instead of it to show "Read More" link ) and modify the content limit "Read More" link.

I'm using Mythemeshop theme. Can any one please help me?

Comment: What theme in MyThemeshop are you using? Some of these themes have custom functions in functions.php for this,

Comment: Ad-Sense theme of mythemeshop.com

Comment: Check the index.php. Does it uses the_content or the_excerpt function or something else in the loop?

Comment: find file here [index.php](https://gist.github.com/wresultsblog/e7f59d23a5e03e54577722d92a93f5a7)

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: /**
 * Shorthand function to check for more tag in post.
 *
 * @return bool|int
 */
function mts_post_has_moretag() {
 return strpos( get_the_content(), '<!--more-->' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'mts_readmore' ) ) {
 /**
  * Display a "read more" link.
  */
 function mts_readmore() {
  ?>
  <div class="readMore">
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Full Article', 'ad-sense' ); ?>
   </a>
  </div>
  <?php 
 }
}
 i found this code in it

Answer (score 0):

**Using CSS :**

Go to Styling Options > Custom CSS and add this:

.readMore {
    display: none;
}

**Using File Editing**

To show full article on homepage find below code in index.php

```
<?php echo excerpt(43);?>
```

replace it with

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

and to remove read more link, find and remove this code

```
<p class="readMore"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php _e('Read More','mythemeshop'); ?></a></p>
```

PS: If you want to show full post on categories, you need to edit archive.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the *index.php*, it calls ***mts_archive_post()*** function.

Go to *functions.php* and locate that function. In this function find **the_excerpt()** or **the_content()** function. It is possible instead of those it will call another custom function (maybe mts_excerpt).

Also try to find a string "Full Article" in the functions.php, then just rename it to your liking.

**Updated:**

Replace

`<?php _e( 'Full Article', 'ad-sense' ); ?> </a>`

with

`<?php _e( 'Read More', 'ad-sense' ); ?> </a>`

You should also find `mts_excerpt();` that accepts the length parameter. Then, simply replace the length to the number of your liking.

Comment: i want to remove button. i can explain my requirement here. refer this image [image](http://imgur.com/a/4wsHO)

Comment: You can achieve that by changing CSS for ".readmore a" selector. Go to "Inspect element" in browser for anchor tag in .readmore div and you will have to remove background-color and set a new color.